# Is it possible to bump my old question without a bounty?

Tags: support, old-questions, bump

I posted a question 3 month ago.

It had low views, 29 at the time of writing, no answer and no comments, it was edited once though and only concerning the presentation.

I'd like to bump it so that it can be visible again.

Is there any way to bump my question into the active questions queue without using a bounty on it or is it the only way for me to do it without any external influence?

(I'm not going to post the link here, unless asked, the meta effect isn't what I'm looking for :))

Comment: Editing bumps - but make sure it's not just a trivial edit; see if there is something you can improve.

Comment: Can you make the question clearer? Does it contain a minimal, complete example?

Comment: I don't really know how I could improve the question, and it does include what is needed to reproduce. Unfortunately, to reproduce the minimal, complete example, I'm depending on at least one third party liibrary which may be why users might not be willing to try it out.

Comment: My gut reaction to the (otherwise very good) question is that you went a little overboard trying to set a stage, there is a lot of contextual padding in the question which make it a lot to read through before you get to the actual meat of the question - which if you ask me basically boils down to "converting" HTML to formatted ePub content using a specific library. Am I right? Let me put it differently: nobody needs to know you're scraping content. That can even be a deterrent to answering.

Comment: @Gimby That's quite interesting to know, I'll try to refine the question as soon as I'll have some time to think about it properly. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the question again, but you should only do this if you *really* improve the question (by making it more clear, or sharing some research you have done in the meantime). Editing will bump it to the front page again, but editing just to bump is considered abuse of the system.

It seems you [already edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36498827/revisions) the question to fix a typo. That's no problem at all, but doing this repeatedly on the same question might get you into trouble.

Comment: The thing is, I did not think that editing my **own** question would bump it. I'm always bothered when I see a mistake in something I made to let it last long.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 yes, it does, and as long as you don't do this *with the intention of bumping the question*, there's no problem.

Comment: Noted: Typo editing of old question is ok if not repeated often. Guess I better check for all the typos in one swoop If I happen to spot one.